# Bootstap 4 Datatable column header not aligned in tbody

Tags: javascript, datatable

Here is my datatable initialization :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "pagingType" : "simple_numbers",
    "lengthChange": true,
    "fnInitComplete": function () {
      var myCustomScrollbar = document.querySelector('#dt-vertical-scroll_wrapper .dataTables_scrollBody');
    },
    "scrollY": 620,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scroller": {
         "rowHeight": 30
     },
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "language": {
           "zeroRecords" : "No Records were found",
           "lengthMenu": "_MENU_"
        }       
});
table.column( 0 ).visible( false ); // hide first column
table.columns.adjust().draw(); // not working
});
```

Photo not mine, but this is same as what my table looks like. Table header is not aligned. [image]
I already set the table width="100%", I have tried Table.columns.adjust().draw(), Table.clear().draw() and some css hacks for 'dataTables_scrollHeadInner' and 'dataTables_scrollHead' as mentioned in some posts but neither of them have worked.
Please note that it only happens when the data is loaded for the first time. The width of the table changes when I click pagination button or even F12 to bring up the dev tool console and looks as expected.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "column header not aligned in tbody"? Please add an screenshot of what does it looks like now and an expected result so we can help you better.

Comment: @xWaZzo I added a sample screenshot, of what my table looks like. My expected result is ti make the table header align.

Comment: Please paste your html code as well.